# Android. Embedding signed apks inside of my asset folder - then installing.

Tags: android

The basis of my question regards installing apks from my asset folders. If the apks come from the store, are downloaded and packaged inside of my app, will the end user still need to select "Install from unknown sources"? Any help or guidance appreciated!

Comment: "will the end user still need to select "Install from unknown sources"?" -- AFAIK, yes.

Comment: As far as the device knows, they didn't come from the store - they came from your app.